# Hyper-V Virtual Switch not recieving any packets

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, sip, mirroring, avaya

I have a virtual machine set up with two network cards, one card is connected to a virtual switch for connection to the main network, the second is connected to another external port on the host server. This second port is connected to a mirrored port on our managed switch, mirroring traffic from our Avaya phone system. The connection to the virtual machine is to allow SIP traffic to flow to Chronicall, a call recording software.

When in the VM, Windows reports that no packets are received by the secondary adapter, Wireshark says different with lots of different traffic passing through this adaptor.

Running Wireshark on the host Hyper-V server shows all the SIP traffic being mirrored by the switch correctly, it just isn't passing this through to the VM. I am thus able to ignore any concerns regarding the switch.

My setup looks like this:
[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5cUk.png)

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell:

PS C:> Move-VM "VMNAME" "DestinationServerName" -IncludeStorage -DestinationStoragePath D:\"VMNAME"

Alternatively, you can do it with Windows 10 Pro machine and Hyper-V manager on it, connect the hosts and Move the VM.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to relate to the issue at hand at all...